# Rotating Google Maps based on header

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to rotate Google Maps default north heading based on the users compass direction. I have no problem getting the mobile devices heading, but I can't seem to apply that to Google Maps.

I see they have examples for this, but it only seems like it's for Arial imagery:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/aerial-rotation

I've tried .setHeading() to no success

Comment: What code have you actually tried? As you noted, rotation only applies to arial imagery. The api does not provide rotation capabilities for any other view.

Comment: OK so it's impossible then if the 2D map stays facing north (unless I try to rotate the canvas or similar). Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

old question, but as there seems to be no simple solution, in case anyone need, I've done a js/css version. (this is the prototype, just swap zoom and rotation values for scale and rotation from touch)

```
using map.panBy(x, y);

http://codepen.io/christianpugliese/pen/yNdPda
```